# Evaluate variable value from string dynamically

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, sh

We need to get the value of dynamically constructed variables.

What I mean is we have a variable loaded from a property file called `data8967677878788node`. So when we run `echo $data8967677878788node` we get the output `test`.

Now in `data8967677878788node` the number part `8967677878788` needs to be dynamic. That means there could be variables like

```
data1234node
data346346367node
```

and such.

The number is an input argument to the script. So we need something like this to work

```
TESTVAR="data`echo $DATANUMBER`node"
echo $$TESTVAR #This line gives the value "test"
```

Any idea on how this can be accomplished

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use BASH's indirect variable expansion:

```
data346346367node='test'

myfunc() {
    datanumber="$1"
    var1="data${datanumber}node"
    echo "${!var1}"
}
```

And call it as:

```
myfunc 346346367
```

**Output:**

```
test
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually already pretty close to working, it just needs to be modified slightly:

```
TESTVAR="data`echo $DATANUMBER`node"
echo ${!TESTVAR}
```

If `$DATANUMBER` has the value `12345` and `$data12345node` has the value `test` then the above snippet will output `test`.

Source: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#indirection